# How to test APIs

Tags: c#, unit-testing, testing, functional-testing

I've started unit testing and I'm trying to perform unit tests on an API wrapper I built for a WSDL Resource I'm using.

I can unit test my classes just fine, but what are the best practices for testing the external API? Should I ever bother testing it? Aside from the tests I to verify connection and parameters and stuff, what are the best methods for making sure my data got properly updated(if I should even be doing that)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What your seeking is called [Blackbox Testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black-box_testing) which stands basically for testing functionallity of the API instead of its structure.

What you normally look for is:

- Incorrect or missing functions
- Interface errors
- Errors in data structures or external database access
- Behaviour or performance errors
- Initialization and termination errors

Google for [Equivalence Partitioning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_partitioning) and [Boundary Value Analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boundary-value_analysis). That should give you an idea of what to test and how.